# Python = dask Vs pandas, error in read_csv

Tags: python, dask

I've got an error on reading a file with dask, which work with pandas :

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.read_csv("./tous_les_docs.csv")
pdf.shape
(20140796, 7)
```

while dask gives me an error :

```
df = dd.read_csv("./tous_les_docs.csv")
df.describe().compute()
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 192999
```

Answer : 
Adding "blocksize=None" make it work :

```
df = dd.read_csv("./tous_les_docs.csv", blocksize=None)
```

Comment: You have to show your CSV file. Was it exported by some non RFC compliant program(for example Excel)? Some csv librarys are more strict or don't handle faulty csv files by default.

Comment: I understood dask was suppose to behave the same way as pandas :-/ ?

Comment: the csv has been produced by pandas with a df.to_csv(path)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that this could happen

> It should also be noted that this function may fail if a CSV file
>   includes quoted strings that contain the line terminator. To get
>   around this you can specify blocksize=None to not split files into
>   multiple partitions, at the cost of reduced parallelism.

http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv

It seems Dask chops the file in chunks by line terminator but without scanning the whole file from the start, to see if a line terminator is in a string.