# Dask ParserError: Error tokenizing data when reading CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I am getting the same error as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752805/dask-read-csv-fails-where-pandas-doesnt), but the recommended solution of setting `blocksize=None` isn't solving the issue for me.  I'm trying to convert the NYC taxi data from CSV to Parquet and this is the code I'm running:

```py
ddf = dd.read_csv(
    "s3://nyc-tlc/trip data/yellow_tripdata_2010-*.csv",
    parse_dates=["pickup_datetime", "dropoff_datetime"],
    blocksize=None,
    dtype={
        "tolls_amount": "float64",
        "store_and_fwd_flag": "object",
    },
)

ddf.to_parquet(
    "s3://coiled-datasets/nyc-tlc/2010",
    engine="pyarrow",
    compression="snappy",
    write_metadata_file=False,
)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 2958, saw 19".
```

Adding `blocksize=None` helps sometimes, [see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902966/python-dask-vs-pandas-error-in-read-csv), and I'm not sure why it's not solving my issue.

Any suggestions on how to get past this issue?

This code works for the 2011 taxi data, so their must be something weird in the 2010 taxi data that's causing this issue.

Comment: Please show your exception. I believe it is likely happening while reading the file's header to compute the meta for the dataframe, not while processing the block(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw file `s3://nyc-tlc/trip data/yellow_tripdata_2010-02.csv` contains an error (one too many commas). This is the offending line (middle) and its neighbours:

```
VTS,2010-02-16 08:02:00,2010-02-16 08:14:00,5,4.2999999999999998,-73.955112999999997,40.786718,1,,-73.924710000000005,40.841335000000001,CSH,11.699999999999999,0,0.5,0,0,12.199999999999999
CMT,2010-02-24 16:25:18,2010-02-24 16:52:14,1,12.4,-73.988956000000002,40.736567000000001,1,,,-73.861762999999996,40.768383999999998,CAS,29.300000000000001,1,0.5,0,4.5700000000000003,35.369999999999997
VTS,2010-02-16 07:58:00,2010-02-16 08:09:00,1,2.9700000000000002,-73.977469999999997,40.779359999999997,1,,-74.004427000000007,40.742137999999997,CRD,9.3000000000000007,0,0.5,1.5,0,11.300000000000001
```

Some of the options are:

- `on_bad_lines` kwarg to pandas can be set to `warn` or `skip` (so this should be also possible with `dask.dataframe`;
- fix the raw file (knowing where the error is) with something like `sed` (assuming you can modify the raw files) or on the fly by reading the file line by line.